# width:100% across partial screen?

Tags: css, width

I have a conundrum: I need the darkest-gray bar you see on the bottom right (after opening the below code locally) spanning across as much space as the browser window will allow WITHOUT crossing over the light-gray section I have set up on the left. Here is my code:

```
<div class="timeline-section">
    <div class="timeline-wrapper">
       <div class="mini-timline"></div>
       <div class="timeline"></div>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix { clear: both; }

.timeline-wrapper { position: relative; }

.timeline-section {
    background: #3d3d3d;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 276px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;}

.mini-timline {
    background: #474747;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    height: 276px;
    width: 500px;
    display: inline-block;}

.timeline {
    background: #232323;
    height: 200px;
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;}
```

Comment: You could help people answering your question by adding a fiddle ... http://jsfiddle.net/D5Jxg/ ... further more it is a nice sandbox for trying out your code yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

One method is not to float the `timeline` element.
Just set a `margin-left` for the width of the `mini-timeline`:

```
.timeline {
    background: #232323;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left:500px;
    position: relative;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rLzAM/1/

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
.timeline {
    background: #232323;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Not a problem. However, this does not appear to work: http://jsfiddle.net/rLzAM/4/

Comment: Worked for me, but when I went to bolden the changes I got double asterisk(s) so if you went verbatim it would fail. Otherwise fine in IE9 and Chrome on W7.

Comment: Does not work for me in Firefox, Safari, Opera, or Chrome. Because it is absolutely positioned and removed from the page flow, the `.timeline` element is either placed above the `.timeline-section` or it does not expand the `.timeline-section` as it should.

Comment: Here's what I see in Safari and Firefox, respectively: http://i.imgur.com/qbHDF3k.jpg